# Grunt connect not living long enough to allow me to test it

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-connect

When I try using Grunt to create a server for me it quickly shuts down and doesn't give me a change to go to my browser and test it.

This is my entire Grunt file:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    grunt.initConfig({
        connect: {
            serve: {
                options: {
                    port: 8081,
                    base: '/',
                    hostname: '*',
                    debug: true
                }
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['connect']);
}
```

When I run it, it works without errors:

```
C:\Users\Imray\my-sandbox>grunt
Running "connect:keepalive" (connect) task
Started connect web server on http://0.0.0.0:8000

Running "connect:serve" (connect) task
Started connect web server on http://0.0.0.0:8081
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the `keepalive` settings dedicated for this :

```
grunt.initConfig({
        connect: {
            serve: {
                options: {
                    keepalive: true,
                    port: 8081,
                    base: '/',
                    hostname: '*',
                    debug: true
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but why do you have to add `keepalive`? Isn't that obvious? Who would want a server that runs for 3 seconds?